# How do you separate javascript files for development?

Tags: javascript

I wanted to create a javascript code library that will be eventually merged into one single minified code file. I was trying to search on how to be able to have these code files separated for development, but I could only find how to have a javascript file add a different javascript file to an existing html page. How do you separate javascript files for development only?

Comment: require.js is what I'd recommend. along with a grunt based build system and almond for your amd loader

Comment: Don't combine them for dev and only combine for prod

Comment: @atmd Op must of done something to combine them, I am saying don't do that on the dev environment and only do that on prod. It seems the root of the issue is that they are combined

Comment: @Huangism I haven't started coding, I want my design to be coherent before I start. I'm just not sure how javascript works with multiple files.

Comment: I would simply combine them into one single file (not minified) and make proper use of source maps.

Comment: The obvious answer is to use ES6 modules and then transpile them to ES5 using 6to5 and then browserify and uglifify them with sourcemaps. Anything else is just sloppy.

Comment: My point being that everyone has their way of working and their opinion on what makes the best dev tool system. It will be worth your time investigating this for yourself. Because everyone's opinion here is both right and wrong for you.

Comment: @Andy I did not realize this was a divided subject. I wrote this question believing there was an objective answer. Sorry!

Comment: @Thegluestickman, no need to apologise. You'll probably see the word "churn" come up from time to time when you read more about JS development when talking about the fractured nature of JS tooling and the like. For example, Grunt and Gulp are both task managers and they're often used for making development builds, but now there's Broccoli which is a proper build system, and tomorrow there'll be something else, not to mention all the frameworks and libraries that are available. It's bloody chaos and everyone has an opinion on what is the best strategy to take.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Develop each module of your library as separate .js files then setup a task running tool such as Grunt. You will need node.js along with npm to install [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/).

You can then use the [grunt-contrib-concat](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-concat) plugin to concatenate your javascript files together, and minify it using [grunt-contrib-uglify](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify).

Comment: So I'm supposed to develop like it was a single file, then combine it after?

Comment: I'd develop the library as modules, so start with a core script, and then create modules that can be included along with the core. Take a look at how jQuery (https://github.com/jquery/jquery) develop their code in organised modules, then build it into a single .js.

Answer (score 0):

These files are separately developed and combined into a single file generally known as **minification and bundling**, you could use asset compressor in Ruby on Rails in case you are developing in Ruby, otherwise pure javascript development uses Grunt based system, check **UglifyJS**.

Comment: *"otherwise pure javascript development uses Grunt based system"* No, I'm fairly certain that not everyone is using Grunt.

Comment: @Felix Kling - I am just trying to  comment an example..I knew there are far superior things...